# JavaFx event like Onload

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

like on Click for buttons , wanna do the the same thing for the load of my screen , i'am using scene builder.
Here is my code:

```
public class CModifierBoutique implements ControlledScreen{
@FXML
ChoiceBox<String> box;        

ScreensController myController;
    @Override
    public void setScreenParent(ScreensController screenPage) {
         myController = screenPage;
    }
@FXML
    private void goToMain(ActionEvent event){
       myController.setScreen(ScreensFramework.screen1ID);
    }    
@FXML    
    private void inialize(ActionEvent event){
        System.out.println(" there is the method who must be start on load this screen ");
        System.out.println("my code is requesting the data base and the result");
        System.out.println("will be added to my choisebox");

        BoutiqueDao dao=new BoutiqueDao();
        List<Boutique> li=dao.DisplayAll();


    }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are just looking for the `initialize()` method. Either your controller can implement the `Initializable` interface and do

```
public class CModifierBoutique implements ControlledScreen, Initializable {

    // existing code..

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        // initialization code here...
    }
}
```

or you can just include a no-argument method called `initialize()`:

```
public class CModifierBoutique implements ControlledScreen {

    // existing code..

    public void initialize() {
        // initialization code here...
    }
}
```

Comment: yes but i would like to load just when screen "x" will be loaded because when i implements the initialize , it works when my first screen will be loaded

Comment: Is there alternative method similar to initialize which works on javafx thread (after GUI is finished loading). ?

Comment: @Mercury Not clear what you are asking. That's exactly what `initialize()` does.

Comment: @James_D if i want to execute something like - button.fire() in initialize() it will give a NullPointerException at runtime. My question was how to run this thing ?

Comment: `initialize` doesnt account for injected beans. it fires before `weld` initializes dependencies.